# how to find other divs with same classname and close them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'd like to know what i should do to show only one div out of multiple divs with the same classname. If one is open and i click another, the one that is open should close, and the one that i clicked on should open.

HTML:

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="content"> <a>click here to learn more..</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="out">
    <div class="content"> <a>click here to learn more..</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="out">
    <div class="content"> <a>click here to learn more..</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.out {
    width:150px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.open {
    border-bottom:5px solid peru;
    height: 150px;
}
.out.open .content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
a {
    display: none;
}
.open .content {
    display: block;
}
.open .content > a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.out').click(function () {
        $('.out').find('open').removeClass('open');
        $(this).addClass('open');
    });
});
```

I know the problem is in the jquery, but i have no clue of what i'm doing wrong.

Here's a fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/4hpgb/22/

Answer (score 2):

Just change this line:

```
$('.out').find('open').removeClass('open');
```

to this:

```
$('.out').removeClass('open');
```

It [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/4hpgb/24/).

What is happening is that you're removing all classes `open` from all `div.out`, then adding class `open` to the current one.

Answer (score 2):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4hpgb/25/)

```
$('.out').click(function () {
    $('.out').removeClass('open');
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Write:

```
$('.out').click(function () {
    if(!($(this).hasClass('open'))){
        $('.out.open').removeClass('open');
    }
    $(this).addClass('open');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hpgb/29/)

Comment: If i add toggleClass to the last line, it works perfectly. just like it want!

Comment: that will close the open div.

Comment: yup :) check out: [link](http://www.digitusweb.nl/nieuw) at the bottom of the page, you'll see "relatie met klanten", "communicatie" and "werkwijze". This is what it was for.

Answer (score 1):

Close all the open divs first

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.out').click(function () {
        $('.out').find('open').removeClass('open');
        $('.open').each(function(i,v){
             $(this).removeClass('open');
        });
        $(this).addClass('open');

    });
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4hpgb/26/)

Comment: Yes this works almost perfectly, my only problem is, why is there a 'function(i,v) ? where does the i and the v stand for?

And another problem, when i click the div again, it won't close..

Comment: that stands for index and value, just wrote thier to show the syntax, no need of it in this code and you said nothing of closing behaviour on cliking the div again

Comment: True that @nouphal.M but it's not your fault. I just forgot to mention it.